# How to prove a series is convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

For this proof, I'm having trouble completing it. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Show that if $a_n > 0$ for all n ∈ N and $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum ln(1+a_n)$
is convergent.

Suppose $\sum a_n$ is convergent

$\sum a_n$

$= a_1+a_2+...+a_n$

$ = S_n$

$\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n = L$

$\sum ln(1+a_n)$

$ = ln(1+a_1+a_2+...+a_n)$

$ = ln(1+S_n)$

Comment: $\sum \ln(1+a_n) \ne \ln(1+a_1+a_2+...+a_n)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the limit comparison test. In order to show $\sum \ln(1+a_n)$ converges, you just need to show that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log(1+a_n)}{a_n}
$$
exists and is nonzero and finite. Since $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, this limit equals
$$
\lim_{x\to0 } \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}
$$
which can be computed using L'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Taylor series, you can check easily than
$$0\le x < 1\implies\log(1 + x)\le x,$$
so
$$0\le\log(1 + a_n)\le a_n$$
and now apply comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Since,
for $x \ge 0$,
$\ln(1+x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
$,
we have
$\ln(1+x)
\le \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1}
=x
$
and
$\ln(1+x)
\ge\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+x}
=\dfrac{x}{1+x}
$.

Therefore
$\sum \ln(1+a_n)
\le \sum a_n
$.

For the other way,
if $a_n \to 0$
and $a_n > 0$,
there is a $N$ such that
$a_n < 1$
for $n \ge N$.

Therefore
 if
$\sum \ln(1+a_n)$
converges
then
$\sum_{n \ge N} \ln(1+a_n)
\ge \sum_{n \ge N} \dfrac{a_n}{1+a_n}
\ge \sum_{n \ge N} \dfrac{a_n}{2}
$
so
$\sum a_n$ converges.